# How can I use a DSN File in a VBA Connection Script?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, dsn

I have VBA code that uses a connection string to talk to an SQL Server. I would like to use an external DSN file for this connection, purely for the adaptability.

The current code:

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
strConn = "DRIVER=SQLServer;SERVER=x;APP=Microsoft Excel;DATABASE=x;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
cn.Open strConn
```

The code works, but for our users a dsn file would be more appropriate.

The .DSN File:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
Database=x
APP=Microsoft Office 2013
Trusted Connection=Yes
SERVER=x
Description=x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `File Name` qualifier to specify a `UDL` or `DSN` file. For example:

```
cn.Open "File Name=c:\path\to\my.dsn;"
```